# How to send push notifications from wordpress to android webview app?

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification

I have `WebView` android app for our website, running on `wordpress` core. 
On the website we are using social network extension, so users can send private messages, reply to the comments and so on. For that we have on website a notification panel.

Now the task:
Is it possible to use the notifications on the website and send it somehow to the android app as push `notification`?
What is the best way to do it? Or is there a developer that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the FCM message sending function to the wordpress server or your server.

After that, you need to add the FCM receiving part in Android and send the device_id to the server so that the FCM message can be received.